# Передача разрешения экрана в php из js, преобразование в int

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно передать ширину экрана в числовом формате в `$screenwidth`. Возможно ли это, в таком примере? Или нужно передавать в `$_GET['width']` и брать значения от туда? Спасибо.

```
$screenWidth= '<script> document.write(screen.width); </script>';
if ( $screenWidth >= 1367) {
    $num_of_adds = 15;
    $num_of_td = 3;
} else {
    $num_of_adds = 10;
    $num_of_td = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тихий ужас.
Во-первых, код в `$screenWidth` никогда не выполнится, ибо разные языки.
Во-вторых, рассчитывать количество строк, ячеек, волос на головах пользователя на PHP - просто бред. Этим должен заниматься CSS с его [`Media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).
В-третьих, передача значений из JS в PHP если сильно нужна (не в этом случае, правда), то есть методы HTTP: GET, POST, DELETE и пр.
[Пример.](http://www.kaminskiy-web.com/stati/kak-peredat-peremennuyu-iz-javascript-v-php.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать в JS, расширение экрана записать в куки. А потом уже с помощью php вытянуть это расширение из куков.